# WebLogic remote hot deploy

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, jdeveloper

I'm workin in JDeveloper with Oracle WebCenter Portal. I've got integrated Weblogic server instance which can easily work with hot-deploy. Also I'm able to declare my remote (standalone) instance as an integrated one. So, as we work in team I've got a question - is it possible to hot-deploy applications on a standalone WebLogic server? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's directly possible to do this with JDeveloper alone, but you might find that you can achieve the goal with something like [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/).